# Delphi: Using XSDateTime without converting time to local time zone

Tags: delphi, utc, datetime-format

I am programming in Delphi and consuming an API that returns an XSDateTime representing an appointment timeslot.  When I try to create a local datatime the time is being converted to my EST timezone (Z-05:00 or Z-04:00 depending on DST).  I need the time to remain in the original timezone of CST (Z-06:00).  I am currently formatting the time as follows:

```
aApptListing := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd t', aSlots[i].StartDateTime.AsDateTime);
```

where StartDateTime comes in as the time in CST (Z-06:00).  How can I keep the original time for CST?  For instance, if the date/time comes thru the API as '2011-12-25T08:00:00-06:00' I want to show 12/25/2011 @ 8:00 AM, not 9:00 AM which would be EST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following should work:

```
with aSlots[i].StartDateTime do
  aApptListing := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd t', EncodeDateTime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, 0));
```